# how to check if two tables / objects are the same identity in Lua

Tags: lua, identity, equality

Is there a way to check if two variables point to the same table in Lua?

I'd like some operator foo(A, B) where:

```
myTable = {1, 2}
myOtherTable = {1, 2}
foo(myTable, myTable)  -- true
foo(myTable, myOtherTable)  -- false
```

Comment: Have you tried the `==` equality operator?! (If metamethods are involved, you may need the `rawequal()` function.)

Comment: You just use `==`. It does exactly what you asked for. What it does NOT do is checking if two tables are equal based on if they contain the same elements or not. You would have to overwrite their metatables' `__eq` method, but you don't need to do that to do what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as mentioned in the comments. Equality sign checks if you work with the same table or not:

```
function foo(a,b)
    return a == b
end

myTable = {1, 2}
myOtherTable = {1, 2}
print(foo(myTable, myTable))  -- true
print(foo(myTable, myOtherTable))  -- false

-- live demo: http://ideone.com/7glzoj
```